# Utorrent hangs after download speed raises

Tags: windows-7, utorrent

when I don't download anything, utorrent works fine, but if I add something to queue, utorrent doesn't show up a window, though the values of download speed at the taskbar changes sometimes, so it is probably still running, but not responding to windows system calls and downloading at very low speed (100kbps vs 5mbps on my old winxp sp3 box). I've tried disabling avira antivirus, but it didn't fix the problem. utorrent version is 1.8.4. OS is Windows 7 x64. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion, ivlBstard, but I've discovered that the reason was HTTP Debugger Pro. If it was running, uTorrent wouldn't work. It's probably connected with the fact utorrent uses http extensively and debugger can't handle all that stuff, so it hangs utorrent)

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling uTorrent and check your uT preferences (ports, encryption, download folders, etc. - suggestion: move the default folder from "Program Files(x86)" somewhere else).

I've got uT 1.8.4 and Win7 x64 RTM, and everything is working as it should, so I don't think it's cause of the OS (1.8.3 beta, and 1.8.3 official worked perfectly on x64 beta and RC as well).

PS - you've got great guides for (advanced) configuring uT all over the net, try'em and see if it helps.

Comment: "but I've discovered that the reason was HTTP Debugger Pro" -- good to know, will have that in mind for future reference
"Thanks for the suggestion" -- you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 7 64 bit and am getting **EXACTLY** the same problem.  Looks like there is an issue with version 1.8.4 because this issue wasn't there this morning.